# Connect to sql file from jdev

Tags: java, database, jdeveloper

How can I connect to a database through JDeveloper via an SQL file? I mean not by writting `String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";` for example but putting the database file inside my project and connect to the file.

Comment: Connect to the file or connect to the database ?

Comment: @kocko the whole database is a file right? an SQL file. I want to connect to the databse THROUGH the file and not through the link.

Comment: The *whole database* is not a file. In JDev you only provide the database address, user credentials, etc. Anyway, I think I have an idea of what you are talking about. Wait a little for my answer.

Comment: @kocko To make it more clear.. I have a project and I want my application to run on any computer regardless of having oracle DB installed.

Comment: Now that makes **much more** sense to me. :)

Comment: You could use [H2DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) to have an embedded, fully Java DB engine always with you... Not exactly Oracle, but quite nice... Just import it as a Maven dependency, and off you go...

Comment: @kocko Good! Any ideas about that..? Take your time, I am not in a hurry

Comment: @Lambros: Oracle keeps its datafiles in the oradata directory. There are a number of files in that directory: a *.DBF file per tablespace, *.CTL files, *.LOG files. The *.SQL files are used for storing SQL scripts, not data. Can you restate what do you mean by "connecting to a database via an SQL file" in a way understandable to people trying to answer your question?

Comment: @ppeterka66 OR, if he has a remote database running (somewhere), he can only provide the proper credentials in the `.adf/connections.xml` file for the application.

Comment: @kocko well, I wouldn't leave a DB wide open to the Internet...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Me too. But it's possible and the connection can be secured for particular IP addresses, for example.

Comment: @kocko Yep. But that is not exactly "on any computer", as OP would like...

Comment: @kocko ok guys let me try again. I have oracle database installed on my system. I am managing it with SQL developer and I am building a custom student database software using JDeveloper. Now.. How can I carry the database with me and show it to my customer's computer with all the data inside, without making the client install the Oracle Database on his PC? I want all the "package" inside the .jar file.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I rephrased my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is not that portable to be embeddable into a JAR file... Zou could have Oracle XE distributed with your application, but that needs installation too... And it is HUGE.

I'd suggest using [H2DB](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

- it is fully Java
- it creates the DB files quick and easy, thez can be included with the app files if zou want
- performance is OK - not an Oracle RAC cluster, but it is not meant to be
- can also work as in memory DB too

Using H2DB is as easy as including in Maven dependencz, and setting up the connection string properly... Downside is that as far as I know, SQL developer does not support H2DB.

I had success with using Apache Derby similarly, to the extent of some tutorial-level experiment in the past.

Comment: Thank you very much all for your suggestions. I will post back any trials and keep the post updated